# How to add a worksheet\delete a worksheet to a shared excel file?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, vba

I am unable to add a worksheet to the excel file I have shared. When tried **"this command is not available in a shared workbook"** message is popping up.

I want to add a worksheet to the same excel file when it is being shared. Please help me doing so.

Comment: I can understand not being able to delete a sheet, but you should be able to add one with no problems.  https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new worksheet. What you can't do (which I suspect you may be doing) is copy an existing worksheet into the shared workbook.